What book I should to read for understanding the 10th section of "The Ricci flow on surfaces"
Picture below is from Hamilton's The Ricci flow on surfaces (237- 262 of this). Most of the picture I can't understand.  I want to know what book I should read ?
I taught myself a little  complex functions. I know Laurent series, Residue theorem and so on. Besides, I know Riemannian geometry and some Ricci flow.



